Error accessing ssh via password in aws ec2 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I set up the following steps to connect to ssh on aws ec2 ubuntu with a password rather than a pem key.

Create a new user
Grant superuser privileges in /etc/sudoers
Change “PasswordAuthentication” to "yes" through “/etc/ssh/sshd_config”
Restart ssh with sudo systemctl restart ssh

However, if you still connect via ssh, the following message appears.
" ubuntu@[myserverIP]: Permission denied (publickey). "
I tried all the methods that came up through Googling, including checking AWS inbound rules and resetting with ssh-keygen -R.
The following is the server connection log.
2024-05-16T15:30:12.605815+00:00 ip-172-31-46-115 sshd[1777]: Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu 124.50.247.56 port 49835 [preauth]
Connection via pemkey still works fine.
I don't know what the problem is.
If you need any logs, please ask for them.
Enter : ssh username@serverIP
result : ubuntu@[myserverIP]: Permission denied (publickey)
It does not proceed to entering the password.

ssh -v username@serverIP should provide some more useful detail.

i dont see thi issue previous version but on AWS linux 24 always give this issue

1 Create a new user
adduser username
2 Set password for the new user
3 Add the user to required group
usermod -aG sudo username
4 Elevate the current user to root
sudo su -
5 Open the sshd configuration file, modify the lines with below lines, save and exit the file
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
6 Restart the ssh service
sudo service ssh restart
sudo systemctl restart ssh
7 Reboot ec2 instance from aws console.
aws console -> Ec2 -> instances -> select instance id -> reboot instance.
Happy Coding.

I followed the steps from Suman and I was not able to log in using password until I found out that there is another folder under /etc/ssh named sshd_config.d
there I found another file with PasswordAuthentication no, so I changed it to yes and restarted the service.

Use grep -r PasswordAuthentication /etc/ssh to find out if the parameter PasswordAuthentication is hidden somewhere else.

Use sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/the_file_you_found(eg.50-cloud-init.conf)

Restart the ssh service
sudo service ssh restart
sudo systemctl restart ssh


